# Data insertion check

Tags: plsql

I have 1 million records and I was upload in database table by using putty but only 0.5 million records are uploaded and got one error msg. How to identify which 0.5 million records are uploaded and which are not?

Comment: Update your question with the error and steps you tried to do to upload it to DB

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and post a [mcve].  Thanks

Comment: I doubt you uploaded them with putty because that's just a program to connect to your server. Also, please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: Are you using Oracle database? what is the error code and error mesaage? paste source code.

Comment: @JamesZ- thanks for your reply and suggestion.

alvalongo - yes i am using oracle database only.. Actually, it was the question which is i faced in my last interview in a reputated company. could you please help me to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Flashback Query. Find all rows, then substract those rows which were not in e. g. 1 day ago. (This works with Oracle 9i and up, for older versions you'll have to analyze the logs.)

```
select * from emp
minus
select * from emp
as of timestamp sysdate - 1
```

The flashback query

```
select * from emp
as of timestamp sysdate - 1
```

gives you the result, how it would have been (in this case) 1 day ago, select the date close before the first row was loaded. This is the data in the table from before the crashed load. Then subtract those rows from the actual table and - voila, you've got all rows inserted since this time.

And by the way, if you are not interviewed for a senior position you are not supposed to know this.